# linux `ctrl + ;` shortcut key behaviour

Tags: shortcut-keys

Normally I use the `Ctrl ;` key inside vscode. But after upgrading my linux ubuntu this shortcut shows strange behaviour which I cannot explain: In any text entry field (terminal/vscode/browser address bar) a `Ctrl ;` press results in an "underscored e". after that any other keypress is blocked but performs all kinds of operations (open a program/back/close etc). After pressing escape all is good again.

I've checked the current keybindings in linux but I've not found any reference to `Ctrl ;`.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

EDIT: I moved from 20.04 to 22.04

Comment: Hello. Upgrade from what to what? There are no versions of Ubuntu mentioned in your question.

Comment: In GTK applications, Ctrl+. is defined to display the emoji picker, as set in ibus-setup and stored in org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey. However, Ctrl+; does the same. Not sure where that is defined.

Comment: Please add version indeed, because this may be quite different between versions.

Comment: @vanadium I also have the impression (gut feeling) it has to do with the emoji picker. But I have no clue how to change that.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.4 is not yet final, so currently your question is out of scope here. It will be good to raise the question again if the issue would persist (probably it will) in the released version.

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009437/ctrl-semicolon-not-inserting-date-in-google-sheets-instead-showing-under